# Configuring FIFO SQS Queue as Cloudwatch Rule Target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

While configuring SQS FIFO queue as a target for CLoudwatch Rule, I got a warning saying "Events will be delivered to the FIFO queue at least once". I wanted to know the explanation behind this warning. In FIFO queue there aren't any duplicates so I want that use case but if I do this configuration can duplicate events be delivered to my Queue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-exactly-once-processing)

> Unlike standard queues, FIFO queues don't introduce duplicate messages. FIFO queues help you avoid sending duplicates to a queue. If you retry the SendMessage action within the 5-minute deduplication interval, Amazon SQS doesn't introduce any duplicates into the queue.

To configure deduplication, you must do one of the following:

- Enable content-based deduplication. This instructs Amazon SQS to use a SHA-256 hash to generate the message deduplication ID using the body of the message—but not the attributes of the message. For more information, see the documentation on the CreateQueue, GetQueueAttributes, and SetQueueAttributes actions in the Amazon Simple Queue Service API Reference.
- Explicitly provide the message deduplication ID (or view the sequence number) for the message. For more information, see the documentation on the SendMessage, SendMessageBatch, and ReceiveMessage actions in the Amazon Simple Queue Service API Reference.

In your case event CloudWatch delivers the same message with-in 5 minutes interval it won't be duplicated in your FIFO when you enable content based deduplication.

Here is [FIFO delivery logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-understanding-logic)

Comment: I get your point and have gone through the documentation as well that FIFO doesnt allow duplication but the warning message says "Events will be delivered to the FIFO queue at least once" for FIFO queue which means that cloudwatch event isnt providing guarantee that the event message will be delivered exactly once. What if after 5 minutes same event again gets delivered else they should not have mentioned the term atleast once for FIFO queue and instead have mentioned ****exactly** once**.

Comment: @SakshamAgarwal here are the sample events https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html of cloudwatch -there is a `time` field in every event. That mean's 6 minutes later when the event pops-up it won't be the same. "Exactly once" is processing - but even your another application which posts to sqs can send same event multiple times - it is not under the cover of "exactly once" - deduplication makes it.

Comment: yeah right so basically I want to distinguish between the duplicate generated by the queue/cloud watch event vs the duplicate event send by some other producer. In my application if a duplicate is send by the producer I want to mark that as an error and raise it to the producer but if cloudwatch in between generates the duplicate then I wont be able to identify this.

Comment: The duplicate generated by cloudwatch(<5 minutes) will be eliminated - the duplicate made by your producer(if it is content based same & < 5 minutes) will be eliminated too. If you want, you may write some custom logic such as your producer sends to lambda you save into some temporary db(dynamodb etc) and check if the record exists in the lambda and then push into sqs. @SakshamAgarwal - but this conversation is beyond the limit of question. please ask in another one, it would be more useful (some other people may help too)